# AIHostAdapter events not working in adobe illustrator 2015?

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

Yesterday i updated my illustrator to 2015  then after updating, All the events from aiHostAdapter files in my extension stopped working although again i have tested extension in 2014 , it is working fine , can anyone tell how to get updated file for 2015.